# How to remove "a" tag in every "cite" tag using php?

Tags: php, html, regex, string, tags

A string contains some `cite` tags with text and links

```
<cite></cite>
```

**Orignal:**

```
<cite>Quote from <a href="/page.php" class="link">Testuser » 29.09.2016 15:08</a>:</cite>
```

**Result:**

```
<cite>Quote from Testuser » 29.09.2016 15:08:</cite>
```

What is the fastest way to remove the link and keep the text only if between cite tags?

Thank you

Comment: More explantion: The Text comes from the database. Its not possible to get the text inside of cite as a string. Before and after the cite is also text and html but only inside of cite should be stripped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing HTML and using DOM is best solution but because you want fastest way, you can use regex. I used [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to finding `cite` tag and iterate selected tags. In callback function use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove HTML tags in selected `cite`.

```
$newStr = preg_replace_callback("/<cite>.*<\/cite>/i", function($matches){
    return strip_tags($matches[0], "<cite>");
}, $str);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/2KQrJ)

Comment: the output is exaclty what I want but I have a error message "unexpected T_FUNCTION". It seems that the php version is to old, is there a other way to write it? thank you very much

Comment: @labu77 It is because in older version of php you can't use `function` in `preg_replace_callback()` parameter. You need to define function and use name of it as parameter. See https://3v4l.org/pbB6S

Comment: thank you very much for your time and effort to providing me a different solution. Works like a charm

Comment: you helped me alot with this preg replace. There is one error with this. When there are more then 1 <cite></cite>  and there is another html tag, like </cite><span>, you code removes everything from the first cite, to the last cite. I hope you understan it. If not, I try to explain it again.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code :

```
<?php
//Function to fetch text from between certain tag
//In our case it will be used to fetch text from <cite></cite> tags.
function everything_in_tags($string, $tagname)
{
    $pattern = "#<\s*?$tagname\b[^>]*>(.*?)</$tagname\b[^>]*>#s";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
//Use srtip_tags function to remove a tag and fetch text.
echo '<cite>'.strip_tags(everything_in_tags('<cite>Quote from <a href="/page.php" class="link">Testuser >> 29.09.2016 15:08</a>:</cite>', 'cite')).'</cite>';

?>
```

Comment: when before or after the cite is html text, its not visible

Comment: Ok so you can append cite open and close tag in to the output. You can check it in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way is:

```
$s = '<cite>Quote from <a href="/page.php" class="link">Testuser » 29.09.2016 15:08</a>:</cite>';
$s = '<cite>' . strip_tags($s) . '</cite>';
```

Comment: The code work if text hasn't any other string except `<cite>`. But in question said *string contains some "cite" tags*

Comment: I cant get the string inside of cite. its a full text from the database with more then cite

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way I can think of

```
$string = '<cite>Quote from <a href="/page.php" class="link">Testuser » 29.09.2016 15:08</a>:</cite>';

$string = '<cite>'.strip_tags($string).'</cite>';
```

Comment: I cant get the string inside of cite. its a full text from the database

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as well

```
 php -r 'print sprintf("%s%s%s", "<cite>", preg_replace("!<[^>]+>!","", "<cite>Quote from <a href=\"/page.php\" class=\"link\">Testuser » 29.09.2016 15:08</a>:</cite>"), "</cite>");'
```